# 'NSString' was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, objective-c, xcode

I'm building a mobile (IPhone) application, I'm new to use the c++ in xcode, this is my code

```
NSInteger myInteger = 42;
int myInt = (int) myInteger;
```

It should work, because I can compile both objective-c++ and c++ in the xcode, but I get this error

```
'NSString' was not declared in this scope
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Show the actual code, along with which line causes the error.

Comment: A strange error to get, when you are using NSInteger and the compiler complains about NSString.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, yes you can write both `Objective-C`, `Objective-C++`, and `C++` using xcode, but you need to make sure what's the file extension you are using.

If it's `.m` this mean you can compile only the objective-c code, and you can't write a c++ code.

If it's `.mm` this mean you can use `Objective-C++` so you may compile a c++ code in this case.

If it's `.cpp` this mean you can **only** compile the c++ code.

Your question not so clear, but I think this problem happen may because the file extension is `.cpp`.

If you are using a `.cpp` file, so you need to change it to .mm file, or not use `NSInteger` and use `int` instead of.

**Edit:**

NSString is an Objective-C type and cannot be used in C++ code, therefore try to compile as Objective-C++, by change the file extension from `.cpp` to `.mm`

Comment: So the answer would be "`NSString` is an Objective-C type and cannot be used in C++ code, therefore try to compile as Objective-C++"?

Comment: Yes, I think the `NSString' was not declared in this scope` will appear mostly because of this (I mean because of the `.cpp` extension.

Comment: Plus the question do not have a lot of details

Comment: Sure, however my comment was to clarify how changing the file extension from `.cpp` to `.mm` will solve the issue.  Your answer doesn't actually explain why doing that will solve the issue.  I do believe you are correct.

Comment: Welcome, but please do not forget to mark my answer as correct answer.